# Drop-down list to select macro to use

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a drop-down in Excel where the user can select a macro from the drop down and the designed macro will run. For instance, selecting "Walmart" from the drop down will the run the Walmart designed Macro. Selecting "Sears" will run the Sears Macro. And so on. I've tried extensive research online, and tried everything from online code ranging utilization of cases to combo boxes and nothing has worked. Really stumped at this for some reason, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Use a Worksheet_Change() event to catch the change and select the proper code to run, but hitting F8 will bring up the list of macros and allow the user to select the proper one to run.

Comment: I tried the worksheet change event, using a data validation drop down, but the macro didn't run. Wondering what the error is:                     
Private Sub Workbook_SelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, Target As Range)
Select Case Range("H2")
    Case "Walmart_Club_March"  End select End Sub

Comment: Not SelectionChange; use Change.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that I wrote recently for a similar issue. Here the dropdown is in cell A1. The macro below resides under the sheet where the dropdown is located, not a separate module. All macros that are being referred to are Public.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("A1")
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Range("M2")
        Case "Macro1": Run "Macro1"
        Case "Macro2": Run "Macro2"
        Case "Macro3": Run "Macro3"
    End Select
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I managed to get the code running, but using the drop down results in frequent crashes. When I run the macro manually(pulling up list of macros), it runs fine. Wondering if you had similar performance issues.

Comment: Sorry, no performance issues on my end. Saying that, each macro of mine was running a simple find and replace statement so I wouldn't really expect and crashes. My only suggestion would be to try some of these tips if you haven't already https://analysistabs.com/vba/optimize-code-run-macros-faster/

Comment: Seem like you aren't the only one having issues https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother-mso_2010/worksheetchange-event-vba-speed-issue/de896df4-4329-4b72-9a5e-a73cf9a2585d

Comment: Also, how many macros do you have. Are Buttons an option opposed to a dropdown? That way you could avoid the Worksheet_Change event...

Comment: Hang on, thinking about it a little more it sounds like the macro you are running it causing the Worksheet_Change event to refire again and again, re running the macro you have selected multiple times. I think disabling events is the way to go. I've updated my answer above to suit.

Comment: @smurfimpulse It will depend on how your macro is set up (the ones you're calling). I suggest you do not include it in `Worksheet_Change` event. Create a dropdown, then add a `Form Button` to call a sub. A sub in module level that checks what is the value selected and then run the code based from it. It gives you better control and stability.

Comment: Hi smurfimpulse, if you are happy with the adjusted answer, please remember to accept it. Alternatively you can post more detail as to why you are still running into issues. Thanks.